# IBM Worklight Application Deployment

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I want to deploy my application on Apache tomcat Server.I went through the documentation part but things were not clear to me..Can Anybody please help me deploying my Worklight application on Apache tomcat.Just want to know the step by step procedure.I am newbie to Apache tomcat,please bear with me.I knw about the .adapter files, .wl.app files but much confused about deploying and accessing the .apk,.war files..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat is an application server. It runs web apps called WAR files (it is not the same as web apps for mobile devices).

You must purchase Worklight for your organization in order to receive additional required libraries, such as the Worklight JEE .jar file, which is basically the Worklight Server and Worklight Console.

You deploy the above files, including the Worklight project's .war file, and its artifacts: the .wlapp and .adapter files, to the Tomcat application server, either manually or by using the installation tools (Ant scripts and the IBM Installation Manager) provided by IBM as part of your license purchasing.